Debouncing input of Mui Autocomplete with react-hook-form
I'm using Mui Autocomplete in conjunction with react-hook-form.
Now to display the options I want to fetch them from the server while I type in the Autocomplete, I would also like to debounce the input.
Now this is how I have create my Autocomplete together with the Control component.
export function FormAutocompleteField<
  TOption extends { id: string | number; label: string },
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
>({
  control,
  name,
  options,
  loading,
  label,
  onInputChange,
  debounceTime,
}: UseControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName> & {
  options: TOption[];
  loading?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  onInputChange?: (input: string) => void;
  debounceTime?: number;
}) {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        const { value, onChange, ref, onBlur, name, disabled } = field;

        return (
          <Autocomplete
            options={options}
            value={options.find((option) => option.id === value) ?? null}
            onChange={(_event, value) => onChange(value?.id)}
            disabled={disabled}
            loading={loading}
            onInputChange={debounce(
              (_event, value) => onInputChange?.(value),
              debounceTime,
            )}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            autoSelect
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                inputRef={ref}
                label={label}
                placeholder={label}
                name={name}
                error={!!error?.message}
                helperText={error?.message}
                slotProps={{
                  input: {
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                      <>
                        {loading ? (
                          <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                        ) : null}
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                      </>
                    ),
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

When I type in the autocomplete the state of the input will be updated with a debounced time, and then the query with useQuery will be automatically re.
export default function useJobOfferForm() {
  const [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState(
    customerOwner &&
      `${customerOwner.contact.name} ${customerOwner.contact.surname}`,
  );

  const form = useForm<JobOfferSchema>({
    defaultValues: {
      status: "Created",
      customerId: customerOwner?.id,
    },
    resolver: zodResolver(jobOfferSchema),
  });

  const customersQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: customersKey({
      page: 0,
      limit: 10,
      filters: { byFullName: customerName },
    }),
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await customerApi.getCustomers(0, 10, {
        byFullName: customerName,
      });
      return res.data;
    },
  });

  function onCustomerNameChange(name: string) {
    setCustomerName(name);
  }

  return {
    form,
    customers: customersQuery.data?.content?.map((c) => ({
      id: c.id,
      label: `${c.contact.name} ${c.contact.surname}`,
    })),
    customersPending: customersQuery.isPending,
    onCustomerNameChange,
  };
}

export default function JobOfferForm({
  defaultJobOffer,
  customerOwner,
  onSubmit,
  onCancel,
  error,
  isPending,
}: {
  defaultJobOffer?: CreateJobOfferDTO;
  customerOwner?: CustomerDTO;
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<CreateJobOfferDTO>;
  onCancel?: () => void;
  error?: Error | null;
  isPending?: boolean;
}) {
  const {
    form,
    customers,
    customersPending,
    onCustomerNameChange,
  } = useJobOfferForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {/* ... */}
        <FormAutocompleteField
          control={form.control}
          name="customerId"
          label="Job creator (customer)"
          onInputChange={onCustomerNameChange}
          loading={customersPending}
          options={customers ?? []}
          debounceTime={1000}
        />
    </form>
  );
}

Now the issue is that when customerName will be updated, the components will be re-rendered. Now from what I understood, the issue is in the fact that the value in the Control component is already set to an option, when the component will be re-rendered it will match one of the options and the input will be set to the previous value.
How can I achieve this behavior (debounced fetch) without breaking the text input in the autocomplete?
Here is a working snippet showing the problem, try to delete some characters and you'll see what I'm tanking about. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-web-share-forked-pkjvyp

To achieve debounced fetching in your Autocomplete component without resetting the input value on re-render, you can try the following approach:

Store the input separately: Use a local state to hold the current
input value, separate from the value prop of the Autocomplete. This
avoids resetting the input when new options arrive.
Use useEffect to update input: Debounce the input with useEffect, so
it only fetches options after the user stops typing.

Update FormAutocompleteField to Hold Local Input State:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash'; // Make sure lodash is installed

export function FormAutocompleteField<
  TOption extends { id: string | number; label: string },
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
>({
  control,
  name,
  options,
  loading,
  label,
  onInputChange,
  debounceTime = 1000, // default debounce time
}: UseControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName> & {
  options: TOption[];
  loading?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  onInputChange?: (input: string) => void;
  debounceTime?: number;
}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  // Update the input value locally and debounce the fetch
  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedFetch = debounce((value) => {
      if (onInputChange) onInputChange(value);
    }, debounceTime);

    debouncedFetch(inputValue);
    return () => debouncedFetch.cancel();
  }, [inputValue, onInputChange, debounceTime]);

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        const { value, onChange, ref, onBlur, name, disabled } = field;

        return (
          <Autocomplete
            options={options}
            value={options.find((option) => option.id === value) ?? null}
            onChange={(_event, newValue) => onChange(newValue?.id)}
            inputValue={inputValue}
            onInputChange={(_event, newValue) => setInputValue(newValue)}
            disabled={disabled}
            loading={loading}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            autoSelect
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                inputRef={ref}
                label={label}
                placeholder={label}
                name={name}
                error={!!error?.message}
                helperText={error?.message}
                slotProps={{
                  input: {
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                      <>
                        {loading ? (
                          <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                        ) : null}
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                      </>
                    ),
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

Usage in JobOfferForm:
Now, onCustomerNameChange will be called only after the user stops typing, and customerName will not reset the input field when new options are fetched.
export default function JobOfferForm({
  defaultJobOffer,
  customerOwner,
  onSubmit,
  onCancel,
  error,
  isPending,
}: {
  defaultJobOffer?: CreateJobOfferDTO;
  customerOwner?: CustomerDTO;
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<CreateJobOfferDTO>;
  onCancel?: () => void;
  error?: Error | null;
  isPending?: boolean;
}) {
  const {
    form,
    customers,
    customersPending,
    onCustomerNameChange,
  } = useJobOfferForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {/* Other form fields */}
        <FormAutocompleteField
          control={form.control}
          name="customerId"
          label="Job creator (customer)"
          onInputChange={onCustomerNameChange}
          loading={customersPending}
          options={customers ?? []}
          debounceTime={1000} // Adjust debounce time as needed
        />
    </form>
  );
}


Your example does not work. When you try to delete some characters the inputValue will reset to the old state. I don't think you can control the Autocomplete when there is already a Control component from react-hook-from. Snippet
